# IE Document mode Compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

There is a legacy application built on `Spring Webflow` and `RichFaces`. Now, we have developed an application which is being rendered inside a modal window from the legacy app. The problem is, it works perfectly fine in Chrome, FF but IE. Some how the legacy application is rendered in IE7 document mode and when we open the new application in modal, it breaks everything. The CSS and JS are not working. I tried using the `X-UA-Compatible` tag and have valid `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` tag, still the issue persist.

Is there a way to solve this issue? How can we render the new application in Document Mode 10 or above?

Comment: Have you checked that the new Window contains HTML that contain X-UA-Compatible Edge ?

Comment: @androidavid if you refer the new Window to the new app, it has this tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>

Comment: Did you use the HTML validator to make sure your HTML is valid? and set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`?

Comment: Actually, it's a jsp page. The first line of code is <!DOCTYPE HTML> and the first line after the <html> tag  is <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is in an iframe, then you would need to set the X-UA-Compatible meta tag on the parent page that contains the iframe.

If you can't do that, you might at least be able to get the legacy application to render in IE11 mode by turning off Compatibility View, if it's currently on.